# django create template with multiple input field

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to create a template which would take input items like item, quantity and unit price and render a pdf report of it with total price. Also i want the input to be on tabular form and add the lines dynamically by clicking + icon or something.

My folder structure is:

```
Project
|__ app
    |__ template
        |__ app.html
```

I am extending app.html from base.html which inherits bootstrap. Tried the below code but can't figure out how to do it.

```
     {% extends 'base.html' %}


            {% block head %}
            {% endblock %}


            {% block body %}


            <div class="panel panel-default">


              <div class="panel-body">

              <div id="all_fields">

                    </div>
                   <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Itemquantity" name="Itemquantity[]" value="" placeholder="Item Quantity">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Quantity" name="Quantity[]" value="" placeholder="Quantity">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Unitprice" name="Unitprice[]" value="" placeholder="Unit Price">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3 nopadding">
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">

                  <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"  onclick="all_fields();"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>

              </div>
              <div class="panel-footer"><small>Press <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus gs"></span> to add another form field :)</small>, <small>Press <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus gs"></span> to remove form field :)</small></div>

            </div>
            {% endblock %}
```

Comment: What is the issue or error you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want dinamic you should go to Javascript instead of Django, because Django is server side, django only will process your data after new request... so you can do it from scratch setting up one ajax to connect to your django while User is interacting with your page and create this new inputs based in something from server... or your inputs will be just generated in your HTML and only after sended to your backend will be hanlded by django (you will have to create your own logic)

Probabily there is any lib that already do that for your.

I do recommend to setup your javascript to dinamic create ids and new inputs, setup all inside one form tag, send this form to your backend, capture it in your post request and handle if... if you receive 5 inputs so it means there i 5 new itens...